# Is $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ invertible?

Tags: functions, inverse, inverse-function

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, then $f^{-1}(x)$ must equal $$y=\frac{1}{x}$$ and after swapping the variables $$x=\frac{1}{y}$$and rearranging to solve for $y$, $$\frac{1}{x}=y$$ that being said, can you conclude that $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{x}$? I know it works since, when you take $f(f^{-1}(x))$ the result is $x$, it's just unheard of to me to have a function whose inverse is itself... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks good.  Lots of functions equal their own inverse.  $f(x)=-x$ for example, but there are more complex ones as well.  See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics))

Comment: Everything correct.

Comment: Every function which is symmetric to the $45^°$ line (i.e. the graph of $f(x)=x$) is its own inverse. Other examples are $f(x)=x$, $f(x)=-x+m$ for arbitrary $m$, $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for $x\in[0,1]$. This is nothing strange, just a geometric observation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might no longer look strange when you consider that from a geometric point of view, inverting a function is just flippes its graph on the $45^°$-line (i.e. the graph of the function $f(x)=x$).

[image]

Now look at the graph of $1/x$, which is perfectly symmetric to this line. No wonder that its inverse is the same. You will immediately see that the graphs of

$$f(x)=x,\qquad f(x)=-x+k,\qquad f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

are all symmetric in the same way (on an appropriate domain), hence they are all their own inverses.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the function is invertible, and is its own inverse. It's also not the only such function, $f(x)=-x$ is another such example.

Comment: Could you show me an example of a function that is not invertible? For reference sake.

Comment: "it's just unheard of to me to have a function whose inverse is itself."

 There are **many** functions that are there own inverse.  f(x)= 1/x is one, f(x)= x is another, f(x)= -x is yet another.

Comment: @joshuaheckroodt For example, $f(x)=1$ is not invertible.

Comment: $f(x)= x^2$ is not invertible over all real numbers though $f(x)= x^2$ with domain "all non-negative real numbers" is invertible.

Comment: @joshuaheckroodt The function $f(x)=\sin(x)$ is not invertible on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are more examples of functions that are their own inverse:
$$f(x)=-x$$
$$f(x)=-\frac1x$$
$$f(x)=x$$
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x+0.5\text{ if }x-\lfloor x\rfloor<0.5\\x-0.5\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
$$\ldots$$